# Displaying private array variable C++

Tags: c++

I get an error:request for member 'module' in 'exams', which is of non-class 'ExamType[12] - This is an work assignment question I do not understand.

Any help will be appreciated.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ExamType
{
public:
    ExamType();
    ExamType(string m, string v, int t, string d);

private:
    string module;
    string venue;
    int time;
    string date;
};

int main()
{
    ExamType exams[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        if (exams.module[i] == "COS1512") cout << "COS1512 will be written on " << exams.date << " at " << exams.time;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read the [markdown help section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for next time

Comment: Just to point out, there's an alt syntax that's a little quicker to write and imo a little easier to read. (Don't take this to mean that you shouldn't learn other syntax :)) `for( decltype(auto) exam : exams ) { if (exam.module == "COS1512") std::cout << "COS1512 will be written on " << exam.date << " at " << exam.time;  }`

Comment: Two problems:   `exams` is an array, so does not have a member named `module`.   That's what the error message is explaining.   You probably intend to write `exams[i].module`, not `exams.module[i]`.    However, that then will trigger another diagnostic from the compiler, since `module` is a `private` member of `ExamType`, so cannot be accessed from `main()`.   To fix that, you will need to define a `public` member function of the class that returns the value of `module`, and call that member function.

Comment: @George why `decltype(auto)` instead of `auto` ?

Comment: @Peter the field for answers is below ;)

Comment: @user463035818 It's just a little generic, `auto` would copy each element. `auto&` or `cont auto&` might be a better choice for non templated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. `module` is `private` and cannot be accessed in `main`. Make module `public` or use a get method.
2. The following will not work:

`if (exams.module[i] == "COS1512")`

It should be:

```
if (exams[i].module == "COS1512")
```

This is because `exams` is an array of the class `ExamType` and there is no array of `module` defined within the class `ExamType`.

Similarly in the `cout` statement, `exams.date` and `exams.time` should be changed to `exams[i].date` and `exams[i].time`.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you P.W, so to use the get method - add string getmodule()
{
    return module;
}
string getvenue()
{
    return venue;
}
int gettime()
{
    return time;
}
string getdate()
{
    return date;
}

Comment: And then in the if statement change to if (exams[i].getmodule == "COS1512")
    cout << "COS1512 will be written on " << exams[i].getdate << " at " << exams[i].gettime;
return 0;

Comment: Yes, you can get values that way. You have to add parenthesis `()` after the function names like this:  `<< exams[i].getdate() << " at " << exams[i].gettime()`

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer satisfies you, you can accept it. (Click on the checkmark). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers